# How is an undefined error handled in javascript HTML W/R/T Later functions

Tags: javascript

I have run into a problem which I have not thought about before.  If I have a `main.js` script that runs on every page, but one or more of my pages does not contain an element that the script references (for instance a contact form is not on a certain page where the script runs) what happens to the code after an error in javascript. It seems like any code after the error does not run, even though I thought Javascript ignores these errors. For instance:
If I have the following code

```
var el = document.querySelector('#el'); //Not a real element
el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Here');
}, false);

//The console errors "can not add eventListener of null"

alert('Test'); //This will never execute?
```

Will that last line never execute?

Comment: I think it's browser-dependent. You shouldn't depend on code after the error executing; if you want the error to be ignored, use a `try/catch` block.

Comment: @Startec, it won't execute indeed. The exception raised by dereferencing the null `el` will break the current frame (unless explicitly caught).

Comment: @FredericHamidi What do you mean by "frame"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x5.2):

> If an algorithm is defined to “throw an exception”, execution of the algorithm is terminated and no result is returned. The calling algorithms are also terminated, until an algorithm step is reached that explicitly deals with the exception, using terminology such as “If an exception was thrown…”. Once such an algorithm step has been encountered the exception is no longer considered to have occurred.

Even though this primarily addresses the algorithms defined in the specification, since the execution of a program is also defined in the spec it also applies to the execution of user land code.

So yes, the last line won't be executed since the program terminates when the errors is thrown.